# Quick simple example for learning delegate event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I'm a new beginner on this topic. I created a **c# win form**. In this form, I have **two textboxes** and **one label**. What I want to do is create a delegate event to track the textbox's change and add up two numbers from `textbox1` and `textbox2`. The label will show the result automatically. Hope someone can provide me a example for this, thank you so much! There is something I have right now,

events.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Project3
{
    public delegate void Calculate(int obj1, int obj2);
    public class events
    {
        int result;
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            result = x + y;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text ="";
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create your own delegate or define a new event. Just write code in `TextChanged` handlers.

Comment: @AVD I know that, but I try to not use those given handlers.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to learn how to **delegate** the result into the label, and learn the `delegate` and `event`, here is a sample you may want to try and analyze for learning purposes:

**Sample 1:**

```
public delegate int CalculateEventHandler(object obj1, object obj2);
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event CalculateEventHandler Calculate;
    private string OnCalculate(string text1, string text2)
    {
        string result = "0";
        if (this.Calculate != null)
        {
            result = this.Calculate(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text).ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeEvent();
    }

    private void InitializeEvent()
    {
        this.Calculate += Form1_Calculate;
    }

    private int Form1_Calculate(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int.TryParse(obj1.ToString(), out a);
        int.TryParse(obj2.ToString(), out b);
        return a + b;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = OnCalculate(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = OnCalculate(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);
    }
}
```

---

**Sample 2:**

*Form1.cs*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeEvent();
    }

    private void InitializeEvent()
    {
        Event.Calculate += Event_Calculate;
    }

    private int Event_Calculate(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int.TryParse(obj1.ToString(), out x);
        int.TryParse(obj2.ToString(), out y);
        return Event.Add( x, y );
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = Event.OnCalculate(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text).ToString();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = Event.OnCalculate(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text).ToString();
    }
}
```

*Event.cs*

```
public delegate int CalculateEventHandler(object obj1, object obj2);
public class Event
{
    static public event CalculateEventHandler Calculate;
    static public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x + y;
        return result;
    }

    static public int OnCalculate( object obj1, object obj2 )
    {
        int result = 0;
        if( Calculate != null )
        {
            result = Calculate(obj1, obj2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: The above examples are by no means a good approach to calculate two values, this just serves as an example. The disadvantage of this approach would lead you to somehow **spaghetti** code, going back and forth to where the logic is going.*

Comment: Thank you! That's a great example! But can you separate event class and form class? I want to have two classes.

Comment: You can (see edited sample). But again this is only for learning purposes, there are better ways to handle the calculation within the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    //textBox2.Text = (0).ToString();
                    label1.Text = ( Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)).ToString();

                }
                else if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();

                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e3.Message);
            }

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    //textBox2.Text = (0).ToString();
                    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)).ToString();

                }
                else if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();

                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e3.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining what you're doing and why